# Access location in JSON2APEX class from Mapquest JSON

Tags: apex, json, parser

I converted Mapquest geocoded data into an Apex Wrapper using JSON2APEX. Now I need to access the location information longitude and latitude:

Mapquest JSON:

```
{
  "info": {
    "statuscode": 0,
    "copyright": {
      "text": "© 2018 MapQuest, Inc.",
      "imageUrl": "http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
      "imageAltText": "© 2018 MapQuest, Inc."
    },
    "messages": []
  },
  "options": {
    "maxResults": -1,
    "thumbMaps": true,
    "ignoreLatLngInput": false
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "providedLocation": {
        "location": "Washington,DC"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "street": "",
          "adminArea6": "",
          "adminArea6Type": "Neighborhood",
          "adminArea5": "Washington",
          "adminArea5Type": "City",
          "adminArea4": "District of Columbia",
          "adminArea4Type": "County",
          "adminArea3": "DC",
          "adminArea3Type": "State",
          "adminArea1": "US",
          "adminArea1Type": "Country",
          "postalCode": "",
          "geocodeQualityCode": "A5XAX",
          "geocodeQuality": "CITY",
          "dragPoint": false,
          "sideOfStreet": "N",
          "linkId": "282772166",
          "unknownInput": "",
          "type": "s",
          "latLng": {
            "lat": 38.892062,
            "lng": -77.019912
          },
          "displayLatLng": {
            "lat": 38.892062,
            "lng": -77.019912
          },
          "mapUrl": "http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=KEY&type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-1,38.892062,-77.019912,0,0,|&center=38.892062,-77.019912&zoom=12&rand=306744981"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON2APEX

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//
// The supplied json has fields with names that are not valid in apex
// and so can only be parsed with explicitly generated code, this option
// was auto selected for you.

public class ClosestStore_Wrapper {

    public class Copyright {
        public String text {get;set;} 
        public String imageUrl {get;set;} 
        public String imageAltText {get;set;} 

        public Copyright(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'text') {
                            text = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'imageUrl') {
                            imageUrl = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'imageAltText') {
                            imageAltText = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Copyright consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Options {
        public Integer maxResults {get;set;} 
        public Boolean thumbMaps {get;set;} 
        public Boolean ignoreLatLngInput {get;set;} 

        public Options(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'maxResults') {
                            maxResults = parser.getIntegerValue();
                        } else if (text == 'thumbMaps') {
                            thumbMaps = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else if (text == 'ignoreLatLngInput') {
                            ignoreLatLngInput = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Options consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Messages {

        public Messages(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Messages consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ProvidedLocation {
        public String location {get;set;} 

        public ProvidedLocation(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'location') {
                            location = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'ProvidedLocation consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Results {
        public ProvidedLocation providedLocation {get;set;} 
        public List<Locations> locations {get;set;} 

        public Results(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'providedLocation') {
                            providedLocation = new ProvidedLocation(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'locations') {
                            locations = arrayOfLocations(parser);
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Results consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Locations {
        public String street {get;set;} 
        public String adminArea6 {get;set;} 
        public String adminArea6Type {get;set;} 
        public String adminArea5 {get;set;} 
        public String adminArea5Type {get;set;} 
        public String adminArea4 {get;set;} 
        public String adminArea4Type {get;set;} 
        public String adminArea3 {get;set;} 
        public String adminArea3Type {get;set;} 
        public String adminArea1 {get;set;} 
        public String adminArea1Type {get;set;} 
        public String postalCode {get;set;} 
        public String geocodeQualityCode {get;set;} 
        public String geocodeQuality {get;set;} 
        public Boolean dragPoint {get;set;} 
        public String sideOfStreet {get;set;} 
        public String linkId {get;set;} 
        public String unknownInput {get;set;} 
        public String type_Z {get;set;} // in json: type
        public LatLng latLng {get;set;} 
        public LatLng displayLatLng {get;set;} 
        public String mapUrl {get;set;} 

        public Locations(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'street') {
                            street = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'adminArea6') {
                            adminArea6 = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'adminArea6Type') {
                            adminArea6Type = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'adminArea5') {
                            adminArea5 = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'adminArea5Type') {
                            adminArea5Type = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'adminArea4') {
                            adminArea4 = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'adminArea4Type') {
                            adminArea4Type = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'adminArea3') {
                            adminArea3 = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'adminArea3Type') {
                            adminArea3Type = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'adminArea1') {
                            adminArea1 = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'adminArea1Type') {
                            adminArea1Type = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'postalCode') {
                            postalCode = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'geocodeQualityCode') {
                            geocodeQualityCode = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'geocodeQuality') {
                            geocodeQuality = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'dragPoint') {
                            dragPoint = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else if (text == 'sideOfStreet') {
                            sideOfStreet = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'linkId') {
                            linkId = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'unknownInput') {
                            unknownInput = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'type') {
                            type_Z = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'latLng') {
                            latLng = new LatLng(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'displayLatLng') {
                            displayLatLng = new LatLng(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'mapUrl') {
                            mapUrl = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Locations consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class LatLng {
        public Double lat {get;set;} 
        public Double lng {get;set;} 

        public LatLng(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'lat') {
                            lat = parser.getDoubleValue();
                        } else if (text == 'lng') {
                            lng = parser.getDoubleValue();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'LatLng consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Info {
        public Integer statuscode {get;set;} 
        public Copyright copyright {get;set;} 
        public List<Messages> messages {get;set;} 

        public Info(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'statuscode') {
                            statuscode = parser.getIntegerValue();
                        } else if (text == 'copyright') {
                            copyright = new Copyright(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'messages') {
                            messages = arrayOfMessages(parser);
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Info consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Info info {get;set;} 
    public Options options {get;set;} 
    public List<Results> results {get;set;} 

    public ClosestStore_Wrapper(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'info') {
                        info = new Info(parser);
                    } else if (text == 'options') {
                        options = new Options(parser);
                    } else if (text == 'results') {
                        results = arrayOfResults(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'ClosestStore_Wrapper consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static ClosestStore_Wrapper parse(String json) {
        System.JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(json);
        return new ClosestStore_Wrapper(parser);
    }

    public static void consumeObject(System.JSONParser parser) {
        Integer depth = 0;
        do {
            System.JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
            if (curr == System.JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
                curr == System.JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                depth++;
            } else if (curr == System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
                curr == System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                depth--;
            }
        } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
    }

    private static List<Locations> arrayOfLocations(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<Locations> res = new List<Locations>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new Locations(p));
        }
        return res;
    }

    private static List<Results> arrayOfResults(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<Results> res = new List<Results>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new Results(p));
        }
        return res;
    }

    private static List<Messages> arrayOfMessages(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<Messages> res = new List<Messages>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new Messages(p));
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

HTTP response:

```
if(res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    ClosestStore_Wrapper wrapperinstance;
    wrapperinstance = (ClosestStore_Wrapper)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), ClosestStore_Wrapper.class);

    System.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'wrapperinstance '+wrapperinstance.Results);
    System.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'acc '+acc);

    //acc.Location__latitude__s = wrapperinstance.Results.locations[0].LatLng.lat;
    //acc.Location__longitude__s = wrapperinstance.Results.locations[0].LatLng.lng;

    //update acc;

}
```

How do I need to modify the APEX2JSON class in order to be able to access lat and lng? Thanks!

Comment: Im not sure I understand the question here, are you talking about during the parsing or after?

Comment: I added the code that processes the wrapper in my question in 'HTTP response'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I notice you did not use the parser, the comment said

> "The supplied json has fields with names that are not valid in apex"

I ran your code and it also worked fine so not really sure what heroku parser was talking about. Never the less I used there custom parser to parse this. You appear to be missing that results is an array of type Results not a single Type Results.

```
if(res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    ClosestStore_Wrapper wrapperinstance = ClosestStore_Wrapper.parse(h);
    // FYI I would check for nulls we are dereferencing and index accessing here.
    acc.Location__latitude__s = wrapperinstance.Results[0].locations[0].LatLng.lat;
    acc.Location__longitude__s = wrapperinstance.Results[0].locations[0].LatLng.lng;
}
```

Comment: Hey yes, thanks, that did the trick!